# Hide overflowing content behind transparent element

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list in which I show the top users, with their corresponding points aligned to the right. Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EkKJC.
I'd like to hide the overflowing part of the username when the viewport is too small. I can't use percentages because they aren't accurate. Neither can I use fixed widths because the content is dynamic.
The main problem here is the transparent background(yes, it must be transparent), because it doesn't work to use z-index.
I need a cross-browser, semantic, css-pure and nested-tag-less solution to this problem, or at leat IE7+. Or maybe another way to handle this situation.
And by the way, I'd like to know if it's necessary(in a semantic point of view) to give the `<span>` a class name, even though I know there will be no other `<span>` in the `<li>`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to refer to the span with javascript or something then no, you don't have to give it a class name. But you also will have to be confident that there won't be any other `<ol>` on the site either, I would tend to give the `<ol>` an id of #topusers

```
ol#topusers {
  list-style: inside decimal;
  width: 300px;
}

ol#topusers li span {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: I did give the ol an id, I just didn't add it in the codepen. In a semantic point of view, isn't it necessary to give it a class name? Because a span doesn't have any meaning. Having read this: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/span, I think it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
body, footer {
background: url('http://static3.depositphotos.com/1000635/110/v/450/dep_1104872-Helix-seamless-pattern..jpg') fixed repeat 100% 100%;
}
```

assuming the reason that the footer has to be transparent is because of the background image.

or, will

```
body {
padding-bottom:(the footer height here);
}
```

help here?

Comment: try to explain your answer instead of just giving it

Comment: I never talked about any footer. Please, read the question again. The same background image wouldn't work because it would have to match the body's background image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use opacity attribute of css to hide the content behind transparent element.

put the content in a div element and then set the opacity of that div.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to hide all the content, just the part that overflows.